# How to trace hits sent by Firebase Google tag Manager in Charles Proxy?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, charles-proxy

We are tracking events and screenviews using Firebase Analytics and Google Tag manager (GTM). GTM will then send the hits to Google analytics (GA).

I believe we have correctly setup the GTM tags needed, inserted the code and installed what needs to be installed as instructed [here](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/10/18/firebase-analytics-for-apps/).

I am now moving on to test if the hits are properly sent by GTM to GA. And we opt to use Charles Proxy to record the hits. Although we can see hits to GA getting recorded, we can't see the parameter 'gtm' from the request. For example, for screenview, the request sent to GA was like this:

[image]

is this expected? Or should we see the GTM Container ID with the request for us to confirm that our setup is working correctly?

Also, is there any other way for us to check if the hits sent to GA is from GTM?

Thank you so much!